# wso2 dss 3.5.0 datasource is not updated when choose google spread private Visibility

Tags: google-sheets, wso2-data-services-server

I tried to follow wso2 instructions to connect wso2 dss 350 to google spreadsheet.(https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/Google+Spreadsheet)

Something is wrong with the "generate token" button. It should upload my datasource with that refresh token, but instead it gave me to blank page https://localhost:9443/authCodeReceiver?code=.

I've tried to use that  but it didn't work.

Is there something I'm missing?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As the refreshing is happening with a session, the same session has to be maintained. Therefore, the hostname in the redirect url and the hostname in the opened management console should be same. For an example if the redirect url is https://localhost:9443/authCodeReceiver then the management console should be opened in the browser should have the url https://localhost:9443/carbon